# Login com Ionic utilizando laravel para o back-end

Tags: laravel, ionic, laravel-5, login, laravel-5.3

Boa tarde.

Alguém poderia indicar algum tutorial de como fazer login com ionic 1 utilizando o laravel 5 ou 5.3 para o back-end?

Att,
Maurício.

Comment: Esse não é o intuito desse site, você deve apresentar um problema concreto relativo ao código e alguma dificuldade que está enfrentando

Answer (score 1):

Opa,
Basicamente o que você faria seria criar uma api RestFull, esse [Blog](https://rafaell-lycan.com/2016/construindo-restful-api-laravel-parte-3/) ensina como criar além da API com Laravel, também a parte de autentificação.

Já esse outro [Blog](https://auth0.com/blog/ionic-2-authentication-how-to-secure-your-mobile-app-with-jwt/) ensina a criar o login e autentificação no ionic usando o token(está em inglês)

Comment: Opa. Desculpa a demora pra responder. Estou numa correria no meu trabalho. Obrigado a atenção. Vou dar uma olhada nesses dois links que me passou. Att, Maurício.